# Laravel allow sub-domain access only to certain routes

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, laravel-6

I'm developping a SaaS application for real estate agents where they can add houses / appartements and list them in a public view / url. They can also add their own domain / sub-domain in order to have custom public URLs. The thing is, since I add the alias related to the domain the user added, all the app is accessible with this new url. What I'd like to do is only allowing the public routes of the properties concerned by the user and prevent the other URLs.

A property has a user_id as well as a domain_id

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing). It should allow you to capture the subdomain (`$account` in the example) if you want to use it later or only add the relevant routes inside the route file.

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: But what if my user didn't configure any sub-domain ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that the domain could be different too. In that case, you're probably better off creating a [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware). Use `$request->getHost()` to get the full domain inside the Middleware. If it doesn't match your domain, then you know it's a client's domain. Set it up to allow the request if it's a client domain and then only apply that Middleware to the routes they should have access to.

Comment: @Maxime This is actually a decent way to go around to do this. You can create a new subdomain under your own domain for each client and add your alias for this subdomain only for each client.

Comment: @Spudly I'll try your solution since it seems the best. I need to register it in the App/Http*Kernel.php right ?

Comment: @Maxime, Yes, that's correct. Follow the documentation link above and that should give you a good understanding of Middleware, how it works, and what you can do with it.